# Composer Patch vs. Custom Module for Vendor Directory Modifications

Tags: module, custom, patches, preference

Is there a general consensus on when you should create a custom module to override core vs when you should use a composer patch?

At present, I need to add `@` to a line of code and feel that a module is a lot more work than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general consensus on when to use a custom module to override core versus when to use a composer patch. It ultimately depends on the specific situation and the needs of the project. In general, if you only need to make a small change to the core code, a composer patch may be a better option because it allows you to make the change without creating a custom module. However, if you need to make more significant changes or add new functionality, it may be more appropriate to create a custom module.